# Catching a (specific) generic Exception raised by an external library

Tags: python

I am using an external library which raises a generic `Exception` in one of it's modules under certain circumstances:

```
if some_condition:
    raise Exception('DSSP failed to produce an output')
```

This only occurs in a few edge-cases, but is still something I want to catch and handle.

So, other than cursing the original coders for raising a generic `Exception`, what are my options here? I only want to catch and handle this particular line in the original code. What is the most Pythonic way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch `Exception` and reraise if it's not the exception you're looking for:

```
try:
    do_thing()
except Exception as e:
    if type(e) is not Exception:
        # Not what we're looking for. Let it pass.
        raise
    handle(e)
```

You can add some other checks if you want to really make sure it's the exception you're looking for, such as examining the exception's `message`.

Comment: Cheers, that's exactly what I was looking for.